# Threads in Android Studio (onClick)

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm using easy code for simple thread which obviously works perfectly on java. 
Once I want to run very similar one on Android Studio (I want to run it after clicking one button) 
Nothing goes well:

My Button

```
public void onClickRoll(View v) throws InterruptedException
    {

        System.out.println("START!");
        t.start();
        while (t.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("Still waiting...");
            t.join(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("EVERYTHING TERMINATED");
}
```

My thread:

```
private static class Sender
            implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Thread.sleep(400);
                    System.out.println("You've already been waiting:" +(float)i*0.4+"s");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
            }
        }
```

Obviously thread isn't supposed to just send some text to console, but even with this has huge problem.

```
Error displayed when I open app:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
```

The Error shows line with `t.start()`

Error is showed to console on start of aplication,
When I run application first time It Thread works correctly (no error), When I click the button again it crashes (with same error), ( I wait 10 seconds to be sure the Thread is over)

What is missing?
Do we have to do something else using treading on Android Studio than just InteliJ?

Additional quesiton:
why this code, dosent work either? It's not a new Thread, but shows same errors:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        wait(400);
        System.out.println("You've already been waiting:" +(float)i*0.4+"s");
    }
```

Comment: Your IDE should have nothing to do with your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- Your IDE (Android Studio) has absolutely nothing to do with your question (I've edited your question to remove the tag)
- In the Android framework, everything sent to stdout, e.g. `System.out.println` is sent to /dev/null - you'll never see it.
- There are very specific requirements around threading in the Android framework. While you can start your own thread if you are really careful, there's almost no situation in which you should, unless you're writing a multithreading framework for Android, and even then, probably not. You should probably read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html
- I'm guessing that you are inducing the problem by joining the main UI thread to your background thread. If you read the info in the developer.android.com guide, you'll see that you should not do anything time consuming on the main UI thread.

Comment: I'll read everything carefully, thanks for your answer, you say there is no many situation we should use Threads, then how to substitute them? It is just for a animation in my application. One remark, everything by 'System.out.println' I see in console, clearly...

Comment: It's not that you shouldn't use threads, it's that you shouldn't create them directly. There are higher-level Android threading constructs.

Your IDE may be intercepting System.out, but without the IDE, this will not go to the standard Android log - see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have code somewhere to create t, such as Thread t = new Thread(...).

As such, you cannot start a thread more that once. Therefore, you should put the create t inside the onClick method. That's the easy part.

To continually use a thread, then you need to communicate with it -- which is way beyond your question.